# Installatio python-twisted 10.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package

I have problem with installation python-twisted package on Ubuntu. When I try sudo apt-get install python-twisted some errors occur

```
Processing triggers for python-twisted-core ...
Processing triggers for python-central ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-twisted-conch
 python-twisted-lore
 python-twisted-news
 python-twisted-runner
 python-twisted-words
 python-twisted
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So when I tried install for example python-twisted-conch similar error occur. Now i don't know what I should install else?

Comment: did you find the problem? because I have the same problem right now..

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same symptoms and it turned out to be caused by two different instances (and locations) of python installation. 
Renaming a non system one to python2 helped.